# How to display image into picture box using image path in database

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

How can I retrieve image into picture box using image path in database? Before this I retrieve from shared folder but its make my system slow when loading image. Then I changes the method wheres I want to retrieve image into picture box using image path that stored in MSSQL database. Hopefully it not slow down my system. Anyone please help me. Here is my code but not work to retrieve image.

```
private void textBoxEmplNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textBoxEmplNo.Text != "")
            {

                string selectSql = "select a.name, a.empno, a.workno, a.icnum, a.passport, a.deptno, a.section, a.designation, b.path from m_employee a inner join m_emp_photo b on b.empno=a.empno where a.empno= @empno";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmplNo.Text);

                bool isDataFound = false;

                try
                {

                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            isDataFound = true;

                            textBoxWorkNo.Text = (read["workno"].ToString());
                            textBoxName.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
                            textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                            textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                            textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                            textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());
                            textBoxDesignation.Text = (read["designation"].ToString());

                            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("@path");
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("" + read["path"].ToString());

```
            pictureBox1.SizeMode=System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Comment: Can you explain what your solution is doing rather than just pasting a piece of code.

Comment: I wish success @Miza ;)

Comment: @CagdasBsn Thanks. Now I have some problem wheres if no image path in database, it will appears "no result found" for employee details. How can I solve it? I want wheres no image found, others text box still get value from database. :(

Comment: if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    pictureBox1.Image= "no result found";
}     pls try!! @Miza

Comment: @CagdasBsn that is not what I want. I have try your previous method to load image and its work. But I have problem wheres if no image path in database, it shows no result at all text box. I want the others text box still get value even though the image path don't have in database.